# VS Code debug webpack with nodemon plugin: Unbound breakpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a template for my future express js projects.

Currently I want to set up debugging.
But I always get unbound breakpoints.

Here are the files I think are important (They are pretty long, sorry for that):

- package.json
- webpack.config.js
- launch.json
- Folder structure
- Unbound breakpoint error
- Console output

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "joi": "^17.3.0",
    "joi-password-complexity": "^5.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mailgun.js": "^2.0.6",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.11",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.13",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mustache": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-ordered-imports": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "name": "web-api-template",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx webpack --mode production",
    "start-production": "npx webpack -w --mode production",
    "start": "npx webpack -w --mode development"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const NodemonPlugin = require('nodemon-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  externals: {
    saslprep: "require('saslprep')",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-16x16.png',
        './node_modules/swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png',
      ],
    }),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].js.map',
    }),
    new NodemonPlugin({
      nodeArgs: ['--inspect=9229'],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "args": [],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "port": 9229,
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "start"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "type": "node",
            "sourceMaps": true,
        },
    ],
    "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

**Folder structure**

[image: Folder structure]

**Unbound breakpoint error**

[image: Unbound breakpoint error]

**Console output**

```
webpack 5.13.0 compiled with 13 warnings in 8376 ms
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): dist/app.js
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect=9229 dist/app.js`
Debugger attached.
2021-02-04 13:36:33 info:       Server running on port 4000
```